# Get WooCommerce product regular price and sale price from a WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, discount

I run mass discounts in a specific category successfully (lets say -50% in category id 123) and everything runs smoothly in product grid, product page and orders. (Wordpress 5.7, Woocommerce:  5.1.0, tried various mass-discount plugins)

However the problem is that when I try to print a list in an admin page through a small plugin I made, I can not get the sale price

I tried:

```
global $woocommerce;
$args = array('post_type'=>'product','post_status'=>'publish','ignore_sticky_posts'=>1);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        global $product;
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
        echo $product->get_sale_price()."<br>"; //prints empty
        echo $product->get_price()."<br>"; //prints the initial price
        echo wc_price( wc_get_price_including_tax( $product ) ).'<br>'; //prints the initial price
        echo $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true ).'<br>'; //prints the initial price
        if ( $product->is_on_sale() ){
            echo 'is on sale<br>'; //it never prints so it does not recognise the product as in sale
        }
    endwhile;
}
```

Why is there no sale price? How can I get it? Most products have variations. The product page has the sale price in all products in the category that the sale runs.

Comment: Some feed back on the code below will be appreciated please.

Answer (score 2):

You need to query "product" **and "product_variation"** **post type** excluding, inside the loop, **"variable" product type** as follows:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'           => array('product', 'product_variation'),
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'      => -1,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
        
        if ( ! $product->is_type('variable') ){
            $active_price  = $product->get_price();
            $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
            
            echo 'Product Id: ' . $product->get_id() . ' <em>(type:  ' . $product->get_type() . ')<em><br>';
            
            if ( $product->is_on_sale() {
                echo 'Sale price: ' . $active_price . ' <em>(regular price: ' . $regular_price . ')<em><br>';
            } else {
                echo 'Price: '. $active_price .'<br>'; 
            }
        }
        
    endwhile;
}
```

It should solve your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It did not solve the issue.Still, if the product has a set sale price as a product or as a variable, then it is working. However, the products that have their price changed (-% discount) by a mass discount plugin, are not showing the get_sale_price/get_price correctly (showing the initial price).